# Integral Modulus Inequality

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

> Given that $\int_0^1{f’(x)dx}=0$ and $\int_0^1{xf’(x)dx}=-1$ , find the maximum value of $\int_0^1{|f’(x)|dx}.$ (Also given- $f(0)=f(1)=0$, and $f$ is differentiable.)

A friend of mine actually came up with this question, and we don’t know if it’s possible to solve or not. We have tried using simple modulus inequalities for integrals, but this gets us nowhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't the problem be stated with some function $g$ in place of $f'$?

Comment: @angryavian edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral $\int_0^1|f'(x)|dx$ is unbounded in $X=\{f\in C^0[0,1]|f(0)=f(1)=0\}$. Here is the proof:

(1) Any function $f\in X$ satisfies the first condition: $\int_0^1f'(x)dx=f(1)-f(0)=0.$

(2) Integration by parts shows that $\int_0^1 xf'(x)dx=-1$ is equivalent to $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 1$.

(3) Now, for $a<\frac{1}{2}$ let $f_a(x):[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ be defined as
$f_a(x)=\frac{x}{a^2}$ for $x\in[0,a]$,
$f_a(x)=\frac{2a-x}{a^2}$ for $x\in(a,2a]$, and $f_a(x)=0$ for $x\in(2a,1]$.

It's straightforward to verify that (a) $f_a\in X$, (b) $\int_0^1f_a(x)dx=1$, and
(c) $\int_0^1|f'_a(x)|dx=\frac{2}{a}$. Therefore, by choosing $a$ sufficiently small we can make the latter integral arbitrarily large. $\square$

Comment: The function doesn’t seem to be differentiable at x=a... I apologise if that wasn’t implicit from the question... I’ve edited it now

Comment: Is “smoothing out” allowed? I’ve remembered reading that not all curves can be represented by functions.

Comment: Thank you so much!